# Compilation Issue with pnet Crate on Windows = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Packet.lib'

Tags: windows, rust

##### Description:

I am attempting to compile a Rust program on a Windows machine that uses the `pnet` crate. Despite having installed all the required tools and dependencies, the compilation fails.

##### Environment:

- OS: Windows 10
- Rust Version: 1.72

##### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a new Rust project with `cargo new my_pnet_project`.
2. Add `pnet` crate to `Cargo.toml`.

```ini
[dependencies]
pnet = "0.25"  # Replace with the version you want
```

3. Run `cargo build` in the project directory.

##### Expected Behavior:

The project should compile without any issues.

##### Actual Behavior:

The compilation fails with the following error messages:

```
= note: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lPacket: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: could not compile `atlantic` (bin "atlantic") due to previous error

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/erdt-cyber/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name atlantic --edition=2021 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=214 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=bc075ce29cde910a -C extra-filename=-bc075ce29cde910a --out-dir /home/erdt-cyber/Documents/gitHub/Atlantic/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/debug/deps --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -C incremental=/home/erdt-cyber/Documents/gitHub/Atlantic/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/erdt-cyber/Documents/gitHub/Atlantic/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/debug/deps -L dependency=/home/erdt-cyber/Documents/gitHub/Atlantic/target/debug/deps --extern csv=/home/erdt-cyber/Documents/gitHub/Atlantic/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/debug/deps/libcsv-29d015f24057f58e.rlib --extern pnet=/home/erdt-cyber/Documents/gitHub/Atlantic/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/debug/deps/libpnet-d2ad988bcd6db621.rlib --extern serde=/home/erdt-cyber/Documents/gitHub/Atlantic/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/debug/deps/libserde-06112e241e2deea9.rlib -L native=/home/erdt-cyber/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-0.4.0/lib` (exit status: 1)
```

##### Troubleshooting Steps Tried:

- Confirmed that Visual Studio Build Tools are installed.
- Tried running the terminal as an administrator.
- I tried mscv gnu and llvm and got this :

```bash
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Packet.lib'


warning: `pnet_test` (bin "pnet_test") generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `pnet_test` (bin "pnet_test") due to previous error; 1 warning emitted

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name pnet_test --edition=2021 src\main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=206 --crate-type 
bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=c113a3f6c480f8f2 --out-dir C:\Users\erdt-cyber\Documents\atl_win\target\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\erdt-cyber\Documents\atl_win\target\release\deps --extern pnet=C:\Users\erdt-cyber\Documents\atl_win\target\release\deps\libpnet-554e6b6d6eddfb2c.rlib -L native=C:\Users\erdt-cyber\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\pnet-0.34.0/lib/x64` (exit code: 1)
```

##### Additional Notes:

Please provide guidance on resolving this issue or troubleshooting steps to diagnose it further.

Comment: "_Confirmed that Visual Studio Build Tools are installed._" but you're building with the MinGW toolchain → are you sure that the `pnet` libraries are installed and configured properly _for MinGW_?

Comment: Or switch to the `msvc` toolchain with e.g. `rustup toolchain install stable-msvc` and `rustup default stable-msvc`

Comment: I tried mscv gnu and llvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Title:** Rust: Resolving LNK1181 Error When Using WinPcap Library

**Answer:**

I encountered a similar issue when compiling my Rust project that depends on the WinPcap library (Packet.lib) on Windows. Here's how I resolved the "fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Packet.lib'" error:

1. **Install the Windows SDK and WinPcap Developer Kit:**

   Make sure you have the Windows SDK and the WinPcap developer kit (v4.1.2 or your required version) installed on your system.
2. **Locate the Packet.lib Library:**

   Find the `Packet.lib` library file on your system. In my case, I located it in `C:\Users\erdt-cyber\Downloads\WpdPack_4_1_2\WpdPack\Lib\x64\Packet.lib`. This is the library we need to link to in our Rust project.
3. **Place Packet.lib in the Visual Studio Library Directory:**

   Copy the `Packet.lib` file to the Visual Studio library directory. The path may vary depending on your Visual Studio version and installation location. In my case, it was:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\lib\x64\
   ```

   Placing the library in this directory allows Visual Studio to find and link it during the build process.
4. **Update Your Cargo.toml:**

   In your Rust project's `Cargo.toml` file, ensure that you have correctly specified the library as a dependency. It should look something like this:

   ```ini
   [dependencies]
   # Other dependencies
   ```
5. **Build Your Rust Project:**

   With the `Packet.lib` library in place and the correct path specified in your `Cargo.toml`, you should be able to build your Rust project without encountering the LNK1181 error:

   ```bash
   cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
   ```

   Make sure to adapt the commands and paths to match your specific setup.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the LNK1181 error and successfully compile your Rust project with WinPcap library dependencies.